# scala/spark: Array not updating in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of LabeledPoints. One LabeledPoint represents a row of sparse data (i.e., data where most values are zero).

The structure is as follows:

```
val lp1 = LabeledPoint(0.0, Vectors.sparse(3, Array(0, 2), Array(1.0, 3.0)))
```

The first array is an array of column indices (imagine a dataframe columns). The LabeledPoint above has values in columns 0 and 2.

The second array is the values. So column 0 has a value of 1.0 and column 2 has a value of 3.0. (Column 2 has a value of 0 so it is ommitted from both arrays)

Problem:
I want to delete column 0. This means column 1 becomes column 0, column 2 becomes column 1 and so on.

My code is as follows:

```
private def internalShiftDownColumnsAfterIndex(index:Int):Unit=
{
  labeledPointRDD.collect().map
  {
    lp =>
      lp.features.toSparse.indices.sorted.zipWithIndex.foreach
      {

        case(colIndex,count) => if(colIndex > index)
        {
          lp.features.toSparse.indices.update(count, colIndex-1)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work. The column index array does not change.

```
val lpnew:RDD[LabeledPoint]=labeledPointRDD.collect().map{.......etc
```

also doesn't work. This gives a compilation error

error: type mismatch;

> [INFO]  found   : Array[Unit] required:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]

So, what is the best way to update the index array?

Comment: Maybe i am wrong, but aren't RDD supposed to be immutable ? Besides `lp.features.toSparse` seems to me create a sparse copy of the original vector, so you are updating just a copy of the indices

Comment: Then why no exception?